# strtok not working as expected, not splitting string

Tags: c, string, char, strtok

I am trying to access the '3' part of a string 'a 3', which is stored in my_str, a char pointer to a string.  am having difficulty accessing the 3 part. When I print my_str I get "a 3" as expected. How do I use strtok to move to the '3' character?

```
if(*my_str=='a'){
        puts("appends case");
        my_str = strtok(my_str, " ");
        my_str = strtok(my_str, " ");
        printf("line number: %s\n", my_str);
        my_str = strtok(my_str, " ");
        printf("line number2: %s", my_str);
}
```

Comment: `strtok(my_str, " "); my_str = strtok(NULL, " ");  printf("line number: %s\n", my_str);`

Comment: "On the first call to strtok() the string to be parsed
       should be specified in str.  In each subsequent call that should  parse
       the same string, str must be NULL."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the second and all subsequent calls to [`strtok()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) requiere that the first argument be `NULL`.

```
if (*my_str == 'a') {
    puts("appends case");

    my_str = strtok(my_str, " ");

    my_str = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (my_str != NULL)
        printf("line number: %s\n", my_str);

    my_str = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (my_str != NULL)
        printf("line number2: %s", my_str);
}
```

you should also check that the return value from `strtok()` is not `NULL`, because if the token is not found in the string, `NULL` is returned, and dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is Undefined Behavior.